# Vertical align items in navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar, vertical-alignment

I have a navbar, and would like all items in it to be vertically aligned. I first tried using flexbox, which lead to having too much space in between the elements, which I fixed by using `float: right` instead of flexbox.

My goal is to have a navbar that looks something like this:
(made in Photoshop)

[image: photoshopped navbar]

But with a different layout.

Here's what I have so far:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #252525;
    color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: rgb(243, 33, 33);
  color: white;
}

.search {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 6vh;
    padding-left: 12px;
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 20vw;
}

input[type="text"] {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 0px none transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background: #181818;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

input[type="text"].dark {
    background: rgb(27, 27, 27);
    color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"].light {
    background: #fff;
    color: #222;
}

input[type="text"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 1.4em;
    width: 1.4em;
    border-radius: 50em;
    background: url(https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/svgs/solid/times-circle.svg) no-repeat 70% 70%;
    background-size: contain;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: min(5%, 20px);
}

input[type="text"]:focus::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    opacity: .3;
    pointer-events: all;
}

input[type="text"].dark::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    filter: invert(1);
}

::placeholder {
    color: rgb(194, 194, 194);
    opacity: 1;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: rgb(194, 194, 194);
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: rgb(194, 194, 194);
}

.create {
    color: white;
    float: right !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    border:0;
    background-color: #343434;
    border: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 250%;
    margin-right: .5vw;
    height: 3vh;
    color: #1f282c;
}

.usericon {
    font-size: 5vh;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-right: 3vw;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Homepage</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.0/css/all.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="topnav">
            <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#profile" style="float:right"><i class='fas fa-user-circle usericon' id="profile"></i></a>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." class="search dark">
            <a href="#create" style="float:right"><i class='fas fa-plus create' id="create"></i></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the result:

[image: my navbar]

The only difference is that I use a custom SVG instead of the font awesome icon, which is why it looks weird.

Is it possible to vertically align **all** items in the navbar? Currently, it looks like the profile image and the plus icon are vertically aligned, but the search bar and home text is not.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: What about setting `.topnav` as flexbox container and vertically aligning all links included by means of `align-items: center;`?

Comment: @bitski tried this, but it resulted in the items being spaced out around the nav.

Comment: @divinedemon Could you please extend your question with an image or a precise explanation of your desired nav layout? Picture shown got 5, you just got 4 nav items.

Comment: @bitski thanks for the question. Basically I want the style of the picture shown, however, as you can tell, the two images are of 2 separate things. All I would like is a vertical align on the input and home text.

Comment: @bitski i edited the post showing what i would like.

Comment: ok, I just cobbled together my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General `.topnav` layout as asked for by:

0. positioning HTML nav items in logical order
1. replacing float with flexbox
2. having all 3 right side nav items share the same flex item `div`
3. making flex container items align vertically and spread out horizontally with the help of flex container properties `align-items`and `justify-content`:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.topnav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #252525;
    color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
}

.topnav a {
    color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: rgb(243, 33, 33);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Homepage</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.0/css/all.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="topnav">
        <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
        <div>
          <a href="#create"><i class='fas fa-plus create' id="create"></i></a>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." class="search dark">                
          <a href="#profile"><i class='fas fa-user-circle usericon' id="profile"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the question, the search input is between the `create` and `profile` elements

Comment: @ksav Oops, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

If you simplify the layout, you can achieve this with just one flexbox container (`.topnav__right`) inside another (`.topnav`).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.topnav {
  border: 1px solid #252525;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

.topnav a {
  display: block;
  color: rgb(236, 236, 236);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: white;
}

.home {
  background-color: red;
}

.create {
  background-color: blue;
}

.profile {
  background-color: green;
}


.topnav__right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.search {
  height: 6vh;
  width: 20vw;
  margin: 0 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="home" href="#">Home</a>
  <div class="topnav__right">
    <a href="#create" class="create">Create</a>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." class="search dark">
    <a href="#profile" class="profile">Profile</a>
  </div>
</div>
```